# Cisco AnyConnect modify name of saved server

Tags: windows, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

The server name in my Cisco AnyConnect drop-down menu contains comments making the address invalid, e.g.

```
vpn.company.org Use-this-one
```

Every time I have to manually remove the comment `Use-this-one` for a valid url.

Where/how can I remove this comment from the servername permanently? I am using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server entries for AnyConnect UI drop down comes from two files -

1. Profiles (*C:\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile\*.xml*)
2. User preferences (*C:\Users\[YOUR_USER_ACCOUNT_NAME]\AppData\Local\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\preferences.xml*)

Server entries are present under "HostAddress", "DefaultHostAddress" in files 1, 2 respectively. Profiles under 1 may not be modified as they get updated upon to connecting to the server (if same profiles are configured in the tunnel group by the admin on the server).

*Preferences.xml* is the file which caches information about your last successfully connected server. I suspect *Use-this-one* is coming from that file. You can modify the content of "DefaultHostAddress" and restart AnyConnect UI to take the modifications into effect. Hope this helps !